# Update bower library with specific branch

Tags: angularjs, git, gruntjs, bower, angular-file-upload

I am using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/v1.1.5) directive to upload files in my app, actually I am using 1.1.5 branch version of this directive, I want to update this to 1.1.6 but actually the master branch is 2.0.x, how I can update the branch installed to specific branch, in this case 1.1.6

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`nervgh/angular-file-upload` has a v1.1.6 tag](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/releases/tag/v1.1.6), you can simply checkout that tag:

```
git checkout v1.1.6
```

The result will be a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), but since you don't intent to commit in that repo, this is fine.